# Why are blank lines being matched in this regexp?

Tags: regex, perl

G'day,

I am using the following Perl fragment to extract output from a Solaris cluster command.

```
open(CL,"$clrg status |");
my @clrg= grep /^[[:lower:][:space:]]+/,<CL>;
close(CL);
```

I get the following when I print the content of the elements of the array @clrg BTW "=>" and "<=" line delimiters are inserted by my print statement:

```
=><=
=>nas-rg             mcs0.cwwtf.bbc.co.uk   No          Online<=
=>                   mcs1.cwwtf.bbc.co.uk   No          Offline<=
=><=
=>apache-rg          mcs0.cwwtf.bbc.co.uk   No          Online<=
=>                   mcs1.cwwtf.bbc.co.uk   No          Offline<=
=><=
```

When I replace it with the following Perl fragment the blank lines are not matched.

```
open(CL,"$clrg status |");
my @clrg= grep /^[[:lower:][:space:]]{3,}/,<CL>;
close(CL);
```

And I get the following:

```
=>nas-rg             mcs0.cwwtf.bbc.co.uk   No          Online<=
=>                   mcs1.cwwtf.bbc.co.uk   No          Offline<=
=>apache-rg          mcs0.cwwtf.bbc.co.uk   No          Online<=
=>                   mcs1.cwwtf.bbc.co.uk   No          Offline<=
```

Simple question is why?

BTW Using {1,} in the second Perl fragment also matches blank lines!

Any suggestions gratefully received!

cheers,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That'll be because `[:space:]` matches newlines and carriage returns as well.

So `[[:space:]]+` would match `\n`, `\r\n`, or `\n\n`.

But `[[:space:]]{3,}` would require three characters, and an empty line is just a `\n`.

`{1,}` and `+` mean the same thing: match the preceding group one or more times.

P.S. A typical newline is `\n` on Unix and `\r\n` on Windows.

Comment: @Andomar, those POSIX character classes can't stand alone; they have to be used inside another pair of square brackets, ie, [[:space:]].

Answer (score 1):

Hm. According to the [Perl regular expression documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), the `[:space:]` character class should not include newlines, as it is supposed be the equivalent of `\s` (except that it recognizes an additional character, vertical-tab, to maintain POSIX compliance).

*However*, having just tested this on 5.10.0, I can verify that it is matching newlines as well. Whether this qualifies as a bug in Perl or in the documentation, I'll leave for the Perl maintainers. But to avoid the immediate problem, use the previous answerer's solution and just use `\s` instead of the POSIX class.

Comment: There is no bug; \s is indeed supposed to match linefeeds and carriage returns, and so is [:space:].  Maybe you're thinking of [:blank:], which only matches spaces and tabs.

Comment: \s stands for "whitespace character". In all regex flavors it includes [ \t\r\n].  http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand

Comment: My bad-- I was conflating the fact that "." in a regex only matches newlines when the /s flag is present.